# One parameter (@RequestParam String tab) - many methods

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I get "tab" from front, his value can be 'profile', 'active', 'summary', 'votes' etc. Each value has its own method. How can I call a method based on the value of 'tab' without using **switch** and **if**. Are there any patterns for this case?

Comment: What are you using this `tab` for? I don't think your business logic is built in a way that it can be easy to maintain and develop later if you have to use `switch` & `if`s for method calls. The design pattern that you can use is *Factory Design Pattern* but the use-case for this is based on polymorphism when you need specific implementations based on a condition.

Comment: You need what is called "consistency". All of your "tab" **objects** (if they have methods you shouldn't call them *value*) should have methods following a name convention. Example: `{ getValue, setValue }`. If you have inconsistent data, there is nothing to abstract from it. Only patterns can be normalized. `(2a + 2b) = 2 * (a + b)`. But you can't do anything with `(3a + 5b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Decorator Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm) is a good solution for that, see the solution bellow:

1. Create an interface to the `Tab`:

```java
public interface Tab {
    String methodName();
}
```

2. Implement the classes for this interface: `ActiveTab`, `ProfileTab`, `SummaryTab`
3. Create an Enum to understand and convert the parameter:

```java
public enum TabTypeEnum {
    PROFILE(ProfileTab.class), ACTIVE(ActiveTab.class), SUMMARY(SummaryTab.class);

    Class<? extends Tab> tabClazz;

    TabTypeEnum(Class<? extends Tab> tabClazz) {
        this.tabClazz = tabClazz;
    }

    public static Tab getTabClazz(String tab) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return TabTypeEnum.valueOf(tab.toUpperCase()).tabClazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

4. Create the Decorator:

```java
public class TabDecorator implements Tab {
    protected Tab tab;

    public TabDecorator(String tab) {
        try {
            this.tab = TabTypeEnum.getTabClazz(tab);
        } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            throw new InvalidTabException(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String methodName() {
        return this.tab.methodName();
    }
}
```

5. Finally, use the decorator:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String getByTabParam(@RequestParam String tab) {
    return new TabDecorator(tab).methodName();
}
```

Se the solution working: https://github.com/armandoalmeida/tab-problem-stackoverflow

Comment: I find another pattern for this "State Machine pattern"

Answer (score 1):

With reflection?

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
Method m = c.getClass().getMethod(value);
m.invoke(c);
```

Where MyClass contains methods with name correspond to the values.

Although I think this is discouraged because Java compiler wouldn't be able to detect errors.